# Tensorflow installation failed on Windows

Tags: windows, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow on a Windows 10 machine (64bit). I am following the official instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows specifically those at "Installing with Anaconda".

All required dependencies (CUDA 8.0, CUDNN 6.1) are installed according to the guidance. The GPU is GTX1080.

The error messages are:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

"找不到指定的模块" means "can't find specified module".

Comment: Try installing tensorflow using wheel file. I've observed when we are doing typical pip install, we get lots of these kind of errors. Also, it should be install in separate env using conda. As it might corrupt some other packages while installing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the problem without further knowledge of your system settings. However, you may try the [TensorFlow on Windows self-check code](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) developed by [mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574081/mrry) before running the installation.